# How do you remove the user name text from Windows 7 login screen?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, login-screen

Does anyone know how to remove the user account name part of the login screen?

Not the user account or picture, just the "text box"

[image]

Comment: EDIT I am going for a minimalist look, I have removed the login picture and all the windows branding my next step is to remove the text that shows the user name. There is only one user and I don't want an added username input. -Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Is that Windows 7 Beta? o.O

I don't think it's possible to remove the actual USER NAME from the log in screen unless you actually modify the theme files which requires knowledge, something I don't have, haha.

** EDIT **

If you actually just want to hide the user name of the computer,

1. Click Start, type gpedit.msc, and then press Enter. This opens the Local Group Policy Editor with the top-level Local Group Policy object open for editing.
2. In the editor, expand Local Computer Policy, Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, System, Logon.
3. Double-click Always Use Classic Logon.
4. Select Enabled, and then click OK.

That way, a username box will also appear (like the password box!) instead of automatically selecting your default account.

Resulting in this:

[image]

Comment: that picture was just for reference, yes it will involve registry editing.

Answer (score -1):

> The Logon screen requires users to type a logon name rather than
>   selecting an account from a list of available accounts. The Logon
>   screen has several features that you can control. By default, the name
>   of the last user to log on is displayed in the **"User Name"** field of the
>   **"Log On To Windows"** dialog box. You can improve security by hiding the
>   user name of the last user to log on. Instead, users will need to know
>   a valid account name for the computer.
>
> To do this:
>
> - Start the **"Local Security Policy"** tool from the **"Administrative Tools"** menu or type secpol.msc at an elevated command prompt.
> - Then, under Local Policies\Security Options, double-click **"Interactive Logon: Do Not Display Last User Name"**. Click Enabled, and
>     then click OK.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff394947.aspx)